# VLC Player start recording and stop using linux command

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, vlc

I am trying to record the live streaming and stopping it after few minutes but i am not able to stop the recording. I am able to create new recording but the script doesnot stop. I am using the following command on ubuntu:-

```
cvlc -vvv http://cab.mpeg --sout "#transcode{}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=ts,dst={CabTest_$NOW.ts}" > video_log 2>&1 &

echo "Start recording the test case...."

run_uiautomator 'test.jar demo.jar' 

com.epl.test.mini.RankingAlgoTest

echo "Stop recording the test case...."

stop
```

this stop command does not stop live recording

Comment: I'm surprised by the 2 lines `run_uiauto... ; com.epl.test....` Do you know this format to work? `com.epl.test...` looks like a java class to me. That won't run by itself in a bash script. `stop` seems problematic too, unless you have a it in your PATH. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter the java class works fine....how to stop?....im not able to stop the recording.

Comment: to rephrase my comments, "I don't think what you've posted is a valid bash script, unless there is something special about how `cvlc` works (very unlikely)". Use shell debugging/trace to see each line, as it is executed with `set -vx` on the 2nd line of your script. Edit your question about with the last line that begins with '+', and any other messages that are emitted after that. DON'T add as comments below ;-)! Good luck.

Comment: @shellter forgot the above code....
what if i simply write




vlc http://cat.videos.com/stream/lab.mpeg
stop




the vlc player records for infinite time....cannot stop

Comment: I understand that your stop command isn't working. I'm trying to help you understand WHY it is not working. Please update your question with `set -vx` output and any additional output as described above so I can help you. (I'm going to be offline for at least 4 hrs). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`stop` is not a valid command in this case. Try `killall -SIGTERM vlc` instead